# efficient approach in using c++ thread/ boost thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have a pseudo code that requires parallelization:

```
int thread_count=8;
for(int i=1;i<100000;i++)
{
do_work(i,record);
}
```

do_work function will work based on i and write outputs to record. Now, I would like to convert this serialized implementation into a multithreading implementation;

I know that I could do something like

```
int thread_count=8;
for(int i=1;i<100000;i++)
{
boost::thread t1(do_work,i,std::ref(record));
}
```

But this will create thousands of threads which will harm performance. I believe the problem posted should be the most natural form that requires multi_threading and I would like to know what is the standard c++ practice to solve this problem... Thank you.

Comment: Do you need portable code or can it be specific to a given platform / toolset? eg VC++ on Windows has PPL which can help with such tasks.

Answer (score 3):

Creating multiple threads helps performance only up to the number of cores you have since each thread can run in its own core and not affect the other. However you said they `do_work()` function writes to a record. If that variable is shared between the threads using a `mutex` in this case will horribly degrade performance even if you are running threads on their own cores.

A spinlock can help in reducing the time overhead of a mutex in this case but it is still based on `std::atomic_flag` (at least `boost::spinlock` is when compiled on GNU g++) which is an atomic variable and will thus require the overhead of syncing caches. You should only look to parallelize this up to the extent where each thread can run in an independent core.

Unless your program is like a server where you need to serve requests without blocking others. In which case a pool of threads (maybe which grows and shrinks dynamically) should be the right option. Servers like Apache also use thread pools in many cases

Comment: Thanks for answering, I think using mutex and its delay is not a great issue for me... The difficulty for me now is, even though I need to run do_work() 100000 times, I shall only create maximal of 8 threads, and once some of the thread is finished, I could then create a new thread and do stuffs ... But what would be the standard practice in doing that? Should I make my own custom code? I believe this should be the most common problem in multi-threading... Thank you.

Comment: You can have the 8 threads running. And pass the tasks to the threads via a thread safe queue. So each thread will wait until it receives a task via the queue. Or you will need to signal the main thread that one of your running threads have finished, so another thread can be created via something like a semaphore or a `future` (look into `std::async`). The overhead of creating a new thread however might be a little more expensive. The implementation of the thread-safe queue will also be important as far as performance is concerned

Answer (score 2):

A good approach would be to use a parallel algorithm, such as [TBB `parallel_for_each`](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/index.htm#reference/algorithms/parallel_for_each_func.htm). Under the hood it is going to create a (global) thread pool for you and schedule chunks-of-work/tasks across all available CPUs without oversubscribing, e.g. it won't create more worker threads than available CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use OpenMP? Just add `#pragma omp parallel for` before loop and enable openmp support for the compiler

Comment: Would it handle all the data race stuff??

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect candidate for threadpool. If you don't need to wait on the results,  simple threadpool would suffice. If you need to wait on the results and do other stuff based on the results you need a future based pool.  I wrote both versions of it in C++ for my work and I would be happy to share if you would like.  Threadpools are great ways to optimally use multicore processor resources.